# How to copy a list of files in folder A to overwrite equally named files in multiple subfolders of folder B?

Tags: linux

I have a list of files in **folder A**:

- **chapter1_en.md**
- chapter2_en.md
- chapter3_en.md

I have a target **folder B** with subfolders (a,b,c,d etc. folder names are arbitrary):

- **folder B**

  - a

    - **chapter1_en.md**
  - b

    - unrelated.md
  - c

    - chapter2_en.md
  - d

    - someotherfile.md
  - e

    - chapter3_en.md

What I want to do:

- for each file in **folder A**
- find the subfolder in **folder B** which contains an equally named file

  - folderA/chapter1_en.md -> folderB/a/chapter1_en.md
  - folderA/chapter2_en.md -> folderB/c/chapter2_en.md
- if found copy (overwrite) the file in the target

Is there are way on the linux command line to achieve it with a (one liner) command?

My use-case is a translation use case where I initially collected files for translation from multiple subfolders into a single folder. After having them back from the translator I want to distribute the files back to their original location. In my case I can assure filenames are unique, but just scattered across different folders not following any naming convention.

Comment: It's much easier to recurse folder B and for each file check if there's one with the same name in folder A. Off-topic here nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

The *linux command line* is not what you think it is. Linux is just a kernel found at the core of a number of Unix-like and non-Unix-like operating systems.

What we call *command line* is code in the syntax of a number of line-oriented usually interactive programming languages or tools. For instance, you can have a `nslookup` command line where you enter DNS queries, a `gdb` command line by which you operate `gdb`, or shell command lines by which you can run commands with arguments and with input/output redirected or connected to other commands.

The Linux kernel, itself does also have a command line. This is a list of directives that are passed by the boot loader to it when it starts. You'll find what it was in `/proc/cmdline`, but that's of no use here.

Many programming languages, line-based or not, can copy files, but programming questions are mostly out of scope on unix.stackexchange.com (they would be on the stackoverflow.com sister site where this question was migrated from though).

Unix shells are in scope though. And you can copy files within them by making them invoke copying commands such as `cp`, `pax`,  `rsync`, etc.

One of those Unix shells is `zsh`

In `zsh`, you can do:

```
for src (A/*(N.)) for dst (B/*/$src:t(N.)) cp $src $dst
```

Which loops over the *regular* (with the `.` glob qualifier) files in `A`, and for each of the files in subdirs of `B` that have the same name (the `t`ail of `$src`) and are also regular, copy it over.